# How can I see whether my iPhone is throttling the CPU or some other resources due to excessive temperature?

Tags: iphone, ios, cpu, temperature

I have an iPhone 12 mini, which runs iOS 15. How can I see whether my iPhone is throttling the CPU or some other resources due to excessive temperature?

Comment: The most obvious is that the screen dims. idk of anything else it's possible to test.

Comment: Is it hot? Have you noticed it getting slower? How's the battery?